# Rerooting a tree in Lazarus with a TTreeView object

Tags: algorithm, delphi, tree, lazarus

I'm drawing a tree with `TTreeView` to simulate a rectangular tree. This tree used in science resembling bracketology in a sports tournament.

The `TTreeView` has a few builtin tools making it easier to be created and displayed. I actually need this to work using a rectangular tree format. I barely got it to work using `TTreeView`. It still has errors on the old root which must become one branch and the new root which will split into 2 branches.

Children below the new root will remain the same. The parent and sibling must be on the other branch of the root. The children will remain the same.  The grandparents and above will become children of the parent until it hits the old root which it will traverse down the children again.

I'm having trouble determining where the old root is and often add an undesired extra node in again. The `CreateDownNode` traverses down the tree. The `CreateUpNode` traverses up the tree.

Here is some of the code:

```
    procedure TfrmTreeListDown.btnSetRootClick(Sender: TObject);
    var
      SelectedTreeMember,
      TreeMember: PTreeViewMember;
      dblBrnchLngth,
      dblLngth: double;
      intNP: integer;
      strSlctText,
      strNewRootParent,
      strTopLabel: string;
      NdRoot,
      NCT,
      NCB,
      NPT,
      NSB,
      NdTree,
      NdTreeBottom,
      NdTreeTop: TTreeNode;
    begin
      if (trvwTextDownBased.Selected = nil) then
        exit;
      trvwTextDownBased.Selected;
      trvwRerootedTree.Items.Clear;
      NdRoot := nil;
      with TestTableForSpeciesData do
      begin
        intOldRoot[0] := NodeCount - 1;
        intOldRoot[1] := NodeCount;
        intOldRoot[2] := NodeCount + 1;
      end;
      if trvwTextDownBased.Selected.Parent <> nil then
      begin
        strTopLabel := trvwTextDownBased.Items[0].Text;
        strSlctText := trvwTextDownBased.Selected.Text;
        SelectedTreeMember := PTreeViewMember(trvwTextDownBased.Selected.Data);
        intNP := SelectedTreeMember^.intNodePos;
        strNewRootParent := trvwTextDownBased.Selected.Parent.Text;
        if intNP in [intOldRoot[0], intOldRoot[1], intOldRoot[2]] then
        begin
          NdTree := trvwRerootedTree.Items.AddFirst(NdRoot, '*New Root*' + strTopLabel);
          TreeMember := PTreeViewMember(trvwTextDownBased.Selected.Data);
          NdTreeBottom := trvwRerootedTree.Items.AddChild(NdTree, strBranchLabel(TreeMember^.intNodePos, 0));
        end
        else
        begin
          NdTree := trvwRerootedTree.Items.AddFirst(NdRoot, '*New Root*' + trvwTextDownBased.Selected.Text);
          TreeMember := PTreeViewMember(trvwTextDownBased.Selected.Data);
          dblBrnchLngth := TestTableForSpeciesData.Species[TreeMember^.intNodePos].BranchLength;
          dblLngth := dblSplitLength(dblBrnchLngth);
          NdTreeBottom := trvwRerootedTree.Items.AddChild(NdTree,  strBranchLabel(TreeMember^.intNodePos, dblLngth));
        end;
        If trvwTextDownBased.Selected.HasChildren then
        begin
          CreateDownNode(trvwTextDownBased.Selected, NdTreeBottom, kboolFirst);
          CreateDownNode(trvwTextDownBased.Selected, NdTreeBottom, kboolSecond);
        end;
        if trvwTextDownBased.Selected.Parent.Text = strTopLabel then
          if trvwTextDownBased.Selected.GetNextSibling = nil then
            NdTreeTop := trvwRerootedTree.Items.AddChildFirst(NdTree, trvwTextDownBased.Selected.GetPrevSibling.Text)
          else
            NdTreeTop := trvwRerootedTree.Items.AddChildFirst(NdTree, trvwTextDownBased.Selected.GetNextSibling.Text)
        else
          NdTreeTop := trvwRerootedTree.Items.AddChildFirst(NdTree, strBranchLabel(-1, dblBrnchLngth - dblLngth));
        if trvwTextDownBased.Selected.Parent.HasChildren then
          if trvwTextDownBased.Selected.Parent.GetFirstChild.Text <> trvwTextDownBased.Selected.Text then
          begin
            CreateDownNode(trvwTextDownBased.Selected.Parent.GetFirstChild, NdTreeTop, kboolFirst);
            CreateDownNode(trvwTextDownBased.Selected.Parent.GetFirstChild, NdTreeTop, kboolSecond);
          end
          else
          begin
            CreateDownNode(trvwTextDownBased.Selected.Parent.GetLastChild, NdTreeTop, kboolFirst);
            CreateDownNode(trvwTextDownBased.Selected.Parent.GetLastChild, NdTreeTop, kboolSecond);
          end;
        if trvwTextDownBased.Selected.Parent.Text <> trvwTextDownBased.Items[0].Text then
          CreateUpNode(trvwTextDownBased.Selected.Parent, NdTreeTop{, NdTreeBottomNSB});
        if trvwTextDownBased.Items.Count <> trvwRerootedTree.Items.Count then
          MessageDlg('Original Tree:' + IntToStr(trvwTextDownBased.Items.Count) + ' does not equal Rerooted Tree:' + IntToStr(trvwRerootedTree.Items.Count), mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);
      end;
  if trvwTextDownBased.Selected = nil then
    trvwRerootedTree.FullExpand;
end;

procedure TfrmTreeListDown.CreateDownNode(const tnOriginal, tnCurrent: TTreeNode; const boolFirstChild: boolean);
var
  tnChild: TTreeNode;
begin
  with trvwRerootedTree do
    if tnOriginal.HasChildren then
    begin
      if boolFirstChild then
      begin
        tnChild := Items.AddChildFirst(tnCurrent, tnOriginal.GetFirstChild.Text);
        CreateDownNode(tnOriginal.GetFirstChild, tnChild, kboolFirst);
        CreateDownNode(tnOriginal.GetFirstChild, tnChild, kboolSecond);
      end
      else
      begin
        tnChild := Items.AddChild(tnCurrent, tnOriginal.GetLastChild.Text);
        CreateDownNode(tnOriginal.GetLastChild, tnChild, kboolFirst);
        CreateDownNode(tnOriginal.GetLastChild, tnChild, kboolSecond);
      end;
    end
end;

procedure TfrmTreeListDown.CreateUpNode(const tnOriginal, tnCurrent: TTreeNode);
var
  PrntTreeMember: PTreeViewMember;
  tnSibling,
  tnParent: TTreeNode;
  intNP: integer;
begin
  with trvwRerootedTree do
  begin
    if tnOriginal <> nil then
    begin
      if tnOriginal.Parent.GetFirstChild.Text <> tnCurrent.Text then
      begin
        tnSibling := Items.AddChildFirst(tnCurrent, tnOriginal.Parent.GetFirstChild.Text);
        CreateDownNode(tnOriginal.Parent.GetFirstChild, tnSibling, kboolFirst);
        CreateDownNode(tnOriginal.Parent.GetFirstChild, tnSibling, kboolSecond);
      end
      else
      begin
        tnSibling := Items.AddChildFirst(tnCurrent, tnOriginal.Parent.GetLastChild.Text);
        CreateDownNode(tnOriginal.Parent.GetLastChild, tnSibling, kboolFirst);
        CreateDownNode(tnOriginal.Parent.GetLastChild, tnSibling, kboolSecond);
      end;
      if tnOriginal.Parent <> nil then
        if tnOriginal.Parent.Text <> trvwTextDownBased.Items[0].Text then
        begin
          PrntTreeMember := PTreeViewMember(tnOriginal.Parent.Data);
          intNP := PrntTreeMember^.intNodePos;
          if intNP in [intOldRoot[0], intOldRoot[1], intOldRoot[2]] then
            tnParent := Items.AddChildFirst(tnCurrent, strBranchLabel(-1, TestTableForSpeciesData.Species[TestTableForSpeciesData.NodeCount + 1].BranchLength))
          else
            tnParent := Items.AddChildFirst(tnCurrent, tnOriginal.Parent.Text);
          CreateUpNode(tnOriginal.Parent, tnParent{, tnSibling});
        end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: So, what is your question, exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to reroot the tree on a different branch.  Are there still prune and graft  procedures that could help?